# Timer between keyboard actions

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a timer between two actions, for example showing an image and then pressing a key on the keyboard. I have tried to start this by trying to measure the time between pressing <kbd>space</kbd>. For example pressing <kbd>space</kbd> starts the timer and pressing it again stops the timer. Then print the time.

I am using pygame as a key pressed tracker.

Here is my code, why is it not working?

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.event.get()

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if key == pygame.K_SPACE:      
            start = time.time()
            if key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                end = time.time()
                print(end - start)
```

I thought it may be the way I try to track the space key; and utilized the helpful comment but still can't get it to work:

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
start_time = None
if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:

        if start_time == None:
            start_time = time.time()
        else:
            print(time.time() - start_time)
            start_time = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the state (or start time) of the first event somewhere.
Currently both your if-clauses will evaluate to True and the time will always be 0.

```
start_time = None
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            if start_time == None:
                start_time = time.time()
            else:
                print(time.time() - start_time)
                start_time = None
```

Comment: I appriciate your quick responce, but I am still not getting anything to show up. Can you run the code to see if it works. I thought it may be the way I call the Space key so I changed it to this:import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
start_time = None
if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:

        if start_time == None:
            start_time = time.time()
        else:
            print(time.time() - start_time)
            start_time = None
but it still doesnt work=(

Comment: Sorry I can not run the code because I haven't installed pygame module and I don't know if your are calling the API correct to fetch key events. But your code can not work because python doesn't know if you press the spacebar the first or the second time.

Comment: Ok I found your second problem: You are calling event.get() only one time obviously. You need to wrap your code in some loop that will run while your game is running.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm pretty sure you need a window for pygame to produce any events. Next, you need to loop until you have 2 <kbd>space</kbd> presses. Here's an example:

```
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Open a window
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.flip()

start = None
end = None
# Loop until both keypresses received
while None == end:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:  # Note you had typo here
                if None == start:
                    start = time.time()
                else:
                    end = time.time()
                    print(end - start)

# Close window
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Awesome you are the best!

Comment: No problem. We all start from the beginning.